# Routing Error No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm starting to learn Ruby on Rails and so far everything was going well, but eventually emerging a problem I can not solve in any way. When I edit the information on my form and I click to give the update it presents me the following error(Sorry for my English, I'm not fluent in the language):

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/grupos/14/edit"

Rails.root: C:/Ruby/Projetos/florarails

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
Routes

outes match in priority from top to bottom

Helper         HTTP Verb        Path                  Controller#Action

grupos_path    GET        /grupos(.:format)           grupos#index 
               POST       /grupos(.:format)           grupos#create new_grupo_path  
               GET        /grupos/new(.:format)       grupos#new
edit_grupo_path 
               GET        /grupos/:id/edit(.:format)  grupos#edit
grupo_path  
               GET        /grupos/:id(.:format)       grupos#show
               PATCH      /grupos/:id(.:format)       grupos#update
               PUT        /grupos/:id(.:format)       grupos#update
               DELETE     /grupos/:id(.:format)       grupos#destroy
```

Here is my code controller:

```
class GruposController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @grupos = Grupo.all
  end

  def show
    @grupo = Grupo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @grupo = Grupo.new
  end

  def create
    @grupo = Grupo.new(user_params)
    if @grupo.save
        flash[:aviso] = 'Grupo salvo com sucesso'
    else
        flash[:erro] = 'Erro ao salvar grupo'
    end
    redirect_to (@grupo)
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:grupo).permit(:descricao)
  end

  def edit
    @grupo = Grupo.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @grupo = Grupo.find(params[:id])
    if @grupo.update_attributes(params[:grupo])
        flash[:aviso] = 'Grupo salvo com sucesso'
    end
    redirect_to grupos_path
  end

  def destroy
    @grupo = Grupo.find(params[:id])
    @grupo.destroy
    flash[:info] = "Grupo excluido com sucesso"
    redirect_to(grupos_path)
  end
end
```

Here is the code of my View:

```
<%= form_for :grupo do |f| %>
    <p>Edição de Grupos</p>
    <%= f.label :descricao, "Descrição:" %>:
    <%= f.text_field :descricao, :size => 40 %>
    <%= f.submit "Alterar Dados" %>
<% end %>
```

Here is the file content routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do 

    resources :grupos
    match 'grupos/:id', controller: 'grupos', action: 'show', via: 'get'
    match 'grupos/:id/edit', controller: 'grupos', action: 'edit', via: 'get'
    match 'grupos/:id/edit', controller: 'grupos', action: 'update', via: 'post' #(When this line is added another error is displayed on the screen >> "Unknown action The action 'update' could not be found for GruposController")

end
```

thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<%= form_for :grupo, url: :grupo_path do |f| %>
    <p>Edição de Grupos</p>
    <%= f.label :descricao, "Descrição:" %>:
    <%= f.text_field :descricao, :size => 40 %>
    <%= f.submit "Alterar Dados" %>
<% end %>
```

Also, You do need in routes that `match` lines. `resources :grupos` will cover for you.

Remove:

```
match 'grupos/:id', controller: 'grupos', action: 'show', via: 'get'
match 'grupos/:id/edit', controller: 'grupos', action: 'edit', via: 'get'
match 'grupos/:id/edit', controller: 'grupos', action: 'update', via: 'post'
```

Comment: @LucasRuy Im glad, `rake routes` will help easier to understand what generates routes file.

Answer (score 0):

First, `POST` actions should be reserved for object creation, not update. Use `PUT` or `PATCH` for updates.

Also, key actions in your controller (`edit`, `update`, and `destroy`) are `private` which should be public in order to be routable. Which is the source of your error in the last section.

In a nutshell, most of your problems would be resolved simply using `resources :groupos`. Which will generate consistent routes:

```
      grupos GET        /grupos(.:format)          grupos#index
             POST       /grupos(.:format)          grupos#create
   new_grupo GET        /grupos/new(.:format)      grupos#new
  edit_grupo GET        /grupos/:id/edit(.:format) grupos#edit
       grupo GET        /grupos/:id(.:format)      grupos#show
             PATCH      /grupos/:id(.:format)      grupos#update
             PUT        /grupos/:id(.:format)      grupos#update
             DELETE     /grupos/:id(.:format)      grupos#destro
```

As a final note, you should user `form_for @grupo` instead of `form_for :gropo`. This will allow your form fields to be dynamically populated from their matching attributes in `@grupo`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. But I tried to use only resources :grupos and had not worked.